# xp_logevent procedure and Unicode message

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it true that [`xp_logevent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186244%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) procedure in Microsoft SQL Server only supports non-Unicode (varchar) messages - even in MSSQL2012?

What would be the best alternative to this procedure that supports Unicode?

Comment: I don't know if it's true, but it would take about 10 seconds to test. Did you try it?

Comment: @Pondlife - it is true in my environment but that does not necessarily mean it is not an issue in the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even on MSSQL 2012.

```
raiserror (N'ğ', 0, 0) with log
```